# Exoplayer 2 Quality Renditions like 320p, 480p, 720p and 1080p

Tags: android, android-studio, playback, exoplayer2.x

I am looking to implement Quality renditions option like (320p, 480p, 720p, and 1080p)the way YouTube supports using Exoplayer 2. Really tried hard to look for answers but could not find anything. As I am new to Exoplayer, henceforth it will be great if I can get some help for the same.

Here is my code for `MainActivity.java`

```
package com.geoffledak.exoplayerfullscreen;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private final String STATE_RESUME_WINDOW = "resumeWindow";
private final String STATE_RESUME_POSITION = "resumePosition";
private final String STATE_PLAYER_FULLSCREEN = "playerFullscreen";

private SimpleExoPlayerView mExoPlayerView;
private MediaSource mVideoSource;
private boolean mExoPlayerFullscreen = false;
private FrameLayout mFullScreenButton;
private ImageView mFullScreenIcon;
private ImageButton btn_settings;
private ExoPlayer player;

private Dialog mFullScreenDialog;

private int mResumeWindow;
private long mResumePosition;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn_settings = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_settings);

    btn_settings.setOnClickListener(this);


    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mResumeWindow = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_RESUME_WINDOW);
        mResumePosition = savedInstanceState.getLong(STATE_RESUME_POSITION);
        mExoPlayerFullscreen = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_PLAYER_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    outState.putInt(STATE_RESUME_WINDOW, mResumeWindow);
    outState.putLong(STATE_RESUME_POSITION, mResumePosition);
    outState.putBoolean(STATE_PLAYER_FULLSCREEN, mExoPlayerFullscreen);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private void initFullscreenDialog() {

    mFullScreenDialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen) {
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if (mExoPlayerFullscreen)
                closeFullscreenDialog();
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    };
}

 private void openFullscreenDialog() {

    ((ViewGroup) mExoPlayerView.getParent()).removeView(mExoPlayerView);
    mFullScreenDialog.addContentView(mExoPlayerView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    mFullScreenIcon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_shrink));
    mExoPlayerFullscreen = true;
    mFullScreenDialog.show();
   setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}


private void closeFullscreenDialog() {

    ((ViewGroup) mExoPlayerView.getParent()).removeView(mExoPlayerView);
    ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_media_frame)).addView(mExoPlayerView);
    mExoPlayerFullscreen = false;
    mFullScreenDialog.dismiss();
    mFullScreenIcon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_expand));
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}

private void initFullscreenButton() {
    PlaybackControlView controlView = mExoPlayerView.findViewById(R.id.exo_controller);
    mFullScreenIcon = controlView.findViewById(R.id.exo_fullscreen_icon);
    mFullScreenButton = controlView.findViewById(R.id.exo_fullscreen_button);
    mFullScreenButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!mExoPlayerFullscreen)
                openFullscreenDialog();
            else
                closeFullscreenDialog();
        }
    });
}

private void initExoPlayer() {

    BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
    TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
    LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();
    SimpleExoPlayer player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(new DefaultRenderersFactory(this), trackSelector, loadControl);
    mExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);

    boolean haveResumePosition = mResumeWindow != C.INDEX_UNSET;

    if (haveResumePosition) {
        mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().seekTo(mResumeWindow, mResumePosition);
    }
    mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().prepare(mVideoSource);
    mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().setPlayWhenReady(true);
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mExoPlayerView == null) {
        mExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.exoplayer);
        initFullscreenDialog();
        initFullscreenButton();
        String streamUrl = "http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/bbbfull/bbbfull.m3u8";
        String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(MainActivity.this, getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().packageName);
        DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory httpDataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(userAgent, null, DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, true);
        DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(MainActivity.this, null, httpDataSourceFactory);
        Uri daUri = Uri.parse(streamUrl);

        mVideoSource = new HlsMediaSource(daUri, dataSourceFactory, 1, null, null);
    }

    initExoPlayer();

    if (mExoPlayerFullscreen) {
        ((ViewGroup) mExoPlayerView.getParent()).removeView(mExoPlayerView);
        mFullScreenDialog.addContentView(mExoPlayerView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        mFullScreenIcon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_shrink));
        mFullScreenDialog.show();
    }
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {

    super.onPause();

    if (mExoPlayerView != null && mExoPlayerView.getPlayer() != null) {
        mResumeWindow = mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().getCurrentWindowIndex();
        mResumePosition = Math.max(0, mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().getContentPosition());

        mExoPlayerView.getPlayer().release();
    }

    if (mFullScreenDialog != null)
        mFullScreenDialog.dismiss();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: does the source you are playing even support those resolutions?

Comment: @njzk2 yes it does. :)